# Fourier Transform of complicated product: $(1+x)^2 e^{-x^2/2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

UPDATE: The problem reduces to this for me:

I ran into an issue with a change of variable integral:

I have $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{iy}{2})^{2}}dx$.

I do the change of variable $u = \frac{x + \frac{iy}{2}}{\sqrt{2}}du$.

This changes the integral to $\sqrt{2}\int\limits_{*}^{*}e^{-u^{2}}du$.  If my new bounds are the same as my old bounds, then I'm done since the integral is known to be $\sqrt{\pi}$.  But since I have done a complex translation I am not so sure.  Can I say that $\infty + i = \infty$ ?

Original Problem:
I need to find the Fourier transform of $g(x) = (x+1)^2e^{-x^2/2}$.

This is defined by:

$$\widehat{g}(y) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)\,e^{-ixy}\,dx.$$

This works out as:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\widehat{g}(y) &=& \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x+1)^2\,e^{-x^2/2}\,e^{-iyx}\,dx\\
&=& \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x+1)^2e^{-x^2/2 - ixy}\,dx.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

But I don't know how to evaluate this. Is using software appropriate for something like this?

Comment: Using software help in a problem of this kind is probably not appropriate. The next step that seems to suggest itself here is to complete the square in $-x^2/2-iyx$ and try to get it into the form $-\frac12(x+\alpha)^2+\beta$.

Comment: Another way would be to calculate first and second derivative of $f(x) = e^{-x^2 / 2}$ and express $g(x)$ as a combination of $f$, $f'$ and $f''$, remember the Fourier transform of $f$ and how Fourier transforms interact with differentiation.

Comment: These are both very good ideas. I'll try them.  Thank you both so much!

Comment: OK I went with the second approach, which boiled down to evaluating $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du$.  I used the fact that this is equal to $\sqrt{\pi}$.  (I don't know how to show this part but I don't know if it would normally be done?

Comment: @Kyle: this is **the** classic: evaluate $I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} \,du$ by computing $$I^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2-v^2}\,du\,dv = \pi $$ using polar coordinates...

Comment: That completely reminds me how we did this exact thing in class.  I feel so thick, haha.  Thanks for the reminder.  So obviously it is fair game then since we proved it in class.

Comment: To give another hint regarding t.b.'s approach, set $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$. Then $g(x)=x^2f(x)+2xf(x)+f(x)$. A basic property of the Fourier transform is that $\widehat{x^nf}(y)={d^n\over dy^n}\widehat f(y)$, up to some normalization (with your definition, I believe it should be multiplied by $i^n$). From here, it should be pretty clear how to find $\widehat g(y)$.

Comment: Well the result we have from class is that $\widehat{f'}(y) = iy\widehat{f}(y)$.  This was sufficient to get me to the point mentioned in the top of the question as an update.  I've almost got it I think.

Comment: The change of variables $u = 2^{-1/2} (x + iy/2)$ is a complex change of variables.  You swap integrating along one line with integrating along another.  The bounds are thus the same for $x$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand the comments correctly, the remaining problem seems to be to find the Fourier transform of $$\color{blue}{f(x) = e^{-x^2/2}}.$$
You can do this by completing the squares and substitution, as outlined in the comments, but I prefer this argument:

Let's compute formally first, deferring the justification of the interchange of differentiation and integration in $(!!)$ to the end of the answer:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dk} \widehat{f}(k) &= \frac{d}{dk} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}e^{-ikx}\,dx \\
&\!\color{red}{\stackrel{(!!)}{=}}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\, (-ix)\, e^{-ikx}\,dx \tag{!!} \\
&=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty i
\left( 
  \frac{d}{dx}e^{-x^2/2}
\right) \, 
e^{-ikx}\, dx \\
&= 
-\int_{-\infty}^\infty i e^{-x^2/2}(-ik)e^{-ikx}\,dx  
&& \text{(integration by parts)}\\
&= -k \,\hat{\!f}(k).
\end{align*}
$$
This gives us the ordinary differential equation $\hat{\!f}'(k) = -k \,\hat{f}(k)$ with the initial condition
$$
\hat{\!f}(0) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}\,dx = \sqrt{2\pi},
$$
which shows that 
$$\color{blue}{\hat{f}(k) = \sqrt{2\pi}\,e^{-k^2/2}}.$$

---

In order for you to be able to check your own work, here's my solution of the exercise (N. S. suggested a slightly different approach, but neither is simpler or more efficient, they come down to the same):

We have $f'(x) = -x\,f(x)$ and $f''(x) = (x^2-1)f(x)$ so that
$$g(x) = (x+1)^2 f(x) = f''(x) -2f'(x) + 2f(x),$$
hence
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{g}(k) 
&= \widehat{f''}(k) - 2\widehat{f'}(k) + 2\widehat{f}(k) \\
&= (-k^2+2ik+2) \hat{f}(k)
\end{align*}
$$
which gives us
$$\color{red}{\hat{g}(k) = \sqrt{2\pi}\,(-k^2+2ik+2)\,e^{-k^2/2}},$$
where you can write $-k^2+2ik+2 = 1+(1+ik)^2$ if you prefer.

---

It remains to justify $(!!)$: Compute
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dk}\hat{\!f}(k) & =
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left(\hat{\!f}(k+h)-\hat{\!f}(k)\right) \\
&= \lim_{h\to0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} \frac{e^{-ikx}}{h}\underbrace{\left(e^{-ihx}-1\right)}_{\large 2i e^{ihx/2}\sin{\frac{hx}{2}}}\,dx.
\end{align*}
$$
Using that $|\sin{\frac{hx}{2}}| \leq \dfrac{|hx|}{2}$ we see that the absolute value of the integrand is bounded above by $|x|e^{-x^2/2}$ which is clearly integrable, so we conclude by the dominated convergence theorem.